How to validate file size in React-Hook-Form?
I want to validate file size in React-Hook-Form. File size must be less than 10MB. If file size exceeds 10MB, an error message "File size must be less than 10MB." will be shown.
import {Controller, useForm} from "react-hook-form";

export const Demo = () => {
    const {control, formState: {errors}} = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            file: null,
        }
    });

    const validateFile = (file) => {
        const fileName = file.split('\\').pop()
        const fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."))
        const allowedTypes = ['.pdf', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.png', '.tiff'];
        if (!allowedTypes.includes(fileType.toLowerCase())) {
            return "Please upload a pdf, gif, jpeg, png or tiff file.";
        }
    };

    return (
        <form>
            <Controller
                name="file"
                control={control}
                rules={{
                    required: 'File is required.',
                    validate: validateFile,
                }}
                render={({field}) => (
                    <FormControl {...field} error={!!errors.file}>
                        <Box>
                            <Button
                                component="label"
                                variant="contained"
                            >
                                File Upload
                                <input
                                    hidden
                                    type="file"                               
               accept=".pdf,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/tiff"
                                />
                            </Button>
                            {!errors.file && <FormLabel sx={{pl: 1}}>{getValues("file")?.split("\\").pop()}</FormLabel>}
                        </Box>
                        <FormHelperText>{errors.file?.message}</FormHelperText>
                    </FormControl>
                )}
            />
        </form>
    )
}

I've studied the react-hook-form documentation and it doesn't cover the use case of file upload. If I don't use any validation libraries like yup or zod, can validation of file size still be implemented in the validateFile function?
